# HTTP requests for nested objects

Tags: python, django, post, httprequest, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to use the library 'requests' (HTTP library for python) to post and update nested objects in django rest framework?

I made a new create method in serializers, but I can't post outside the shell,  nor with the requests library or in the api webview.

My Serializers:

```
class QualityParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = QualityParameter
        fields = ("id","name", "value")


class ProductQualityMonitorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    parameters = QualityParameterSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductQualityMonitor
        fields = ("id","product_name", "area", "timeslot", "processing_line",
          "updated_on",'parameters')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        params_data = validated_data.pop('parameters')
        product = ProductQualityMonitor.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for param_data in params_data:
            QualityParameter.objects.create(product=product, **param_data)
        return product
```

[POST HTTP request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Do you want to post data using python 'requests' to a webserver which has a DRF handler ?

Comment: i was using python 'requests' with tastypie, and now I am moving the system to rest framework and I am trying to adapt the code that I already have. I don't know if it is possible to continue with the python 'requests' or not. There is a easiest way?

Comment: If you're referring to http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ then that is a client side (sort of) library, whereas Django Rest Framework is a server side library. I see no reason why they shouldn't work together, one on the client and one on the server - the glue between them should be the JSON over HTTP. Did I get that right ?

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest the following form for your serializer:

```python
from django.db import transaction

class ProductQualityMonitorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    parameters = QualityParameterSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductQualityMonitor
        fields = (
            "id",
            "updated_on",
            "product_name", 
            "area", 
            "timeslot", 
            "processing_line", 
            "parameters", 
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # we will use transactions, so that if one of the Paramater objects isn't valid
        # that we will rollback even the parent ProductQualityMonitor object creation, 
        # leaving no dangling objects in the database
        params_data = validated_data.pop('parameters')
        with transaction.atomic():
            product = ProductQualityMonitor.objects.create(**validated_data)
            # you can create the objects in a batch, hitting the dB only once
            params = [QualityParameter(product=product, **param) for param in params_data]
            QualityParameter.objects.bulk_create(params)

        return product
```

About using python requests library: you will have to pay attention to the following aspects when posting to a django back-end:

- you must provide a valid CSRF token in your request; the way this is done is via csrf-token cookie;
- you must provide the proper authentication headers / tokens / cookies; this is your choice, depends how you're implementing this on the DRF back-end
- if this is a request from one domain to another domain, then you have to care for CORS setup.

More to the point: what have you tried already and didn't worked ?

Comment: I found the error: a name of one quality parameter in the post http request was not the same as in the model, I had "histogram frequencEIs" instead of "histogram frequencIEs". Such a stupid error, sorry!
Your create method is working fine, such as mine.